# python exceptions decorators

Tags: python, exception, decorator

Task 1: Write your own exception (your class) 'AuthError' raise ->
ArithmeticError(AuthError)

Task 2: write a decorator that, in case of missing data (inside request_from_user)
from authorization raises an 'AuthError' exception

Task 3: if successful, return Object (class) 'RequestManager' + 2 methods for validation

Task 4: Implement a "Help class" in which to implement at least 3 methods that you will need in the future. And also save the constant Pi as a property of the class.

```
request_from_user1 = {
    "url": "localhost/home/",
    "method": "GET",
    "data": {"попытка входа": 1},
    "timeout": 3000,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer admin qwerty12345',
    },
}

request_from_user2 = {
    "url": "localhost/",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": {"попытка входа": 1},
    "timeout": 3000,
    "headers": {},
}



class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, exception_text: str):
        self.exception_text = exception_text

    def return_error(self):
        return f'ATTENTION: AN ERROR HAS OCCURSED: {self.exception_text}'

def check_user_request():
    try:
        raise AuthError(exception_text="incorrect login")
        
    except AuthError as error:
        error = error.return_error()
        print(error)

print(check_user_request())
```

My attempt, but i dont know what to do next, can you help me please

Comment: Questions involving the interpretation of the requirements for an assignment are better asked of your teacher, rather than a bunch of strangers who don't know anything about your class.

Comment: ahahahaha, I agree with you, but 
I'll leave this for the end